# Operadores logicos Java

Tags: java, android, operador

Hola, estoy desarrollando una app en android studio, estoy haciendo unas validaciones.

Si alguno de los edittext esta vacio entonces no haga nada y si no lo estan, pasen a una segunda activity.

**El problema es:**

> -si todos los edditext estan vacios no pasa a la segunda activity.
>
> -si el primer edditext de la validacion tiene texto y los otros no, no pasa a la segunda activity.
>
> -si el segundo o tercer edditetx si tiene texto, entonces si pasa a la segunda activity.

Estuve leyendo algo y decia que lo valida de derecha a izquierda, pero entonces como puedo lograr que si alguno de los edditext no tiene texto, entonces no pase al siguiente activity?

```
 if ((Titulo_.length()== 0) && (Ubicacion_.length()== 0) && (Area_.length()== 0){//no hace nada }
 else{ Intent intent = new Intent(CatTegnologiaActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
```

startActivity(intent);}

Comment: `si alguno de los edditext no tiene texto, entonces no pase al siguiente activity` entonces cambia el operador `&&` por el operador `||`

Comment: Según lo que dices, el `Intent` sólo ocurriría en un caso: cuando el 2º o 3º edittext tenga texto. Podrías resolverlo entonces así. En este ejemplo guardo el valor de cada edittext en `txtA, txtB, txtC...` Se verifica también que no sean nulos: **`boolean statusA= txtA == null || txtA.trim().isEmpty(); boolean statusB= txtB == null || txtB.trim().isEmpty(); boolean statusC= txtC == null || txtC.trim().isEmpty(); boolean passSecond= (!statusB) || (!statusC);  if (passSecond){ Intent intent = new Intent(CatTegnologiaActivity.this, HomeActivity.class); startActivity(intent); }`**

Answer (score 1):

Si estas realizando tu lógica de acuerdo a la longitud del contenido dentro de los `EditText` mediante `length()` es importante saber que aún un espacio en blanco genera una longitud de contenido en la vista.

Te sugiero revisar estos métodos:

> [trim()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim()) Devuelve una cadena cuyo valor es esta cadena, con
>   cualquier espacio en blanco inicial y final eliminado.

y

> [isEmpty()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) Devuelve true si, y solo si, length() es 0.

Estos métodos pueden ser muy utiles para realizar lo que deseas:

> Si alguno de los edittext esta vacio entonces no haga nada y si no lo
>   estan, pasen a una segunda activity.

```
  if ((Titulo_.getText().toString().trim().length()== 0) || (Ubicacion_.getText().toString().trim().length()== 0) || (Area_.getText().toString().trim().length()== 0){
          //no hace nada 
          }else{ 
Intent intent = new Intent(CatTegnologiaActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
          }
```

También puedes hacer uso del método  [isEmpty()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) :

```
  if ((Titulo_.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()== 0) || (Ubicacion_.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()== 0) || (Area_.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()== 0){
          //no hace nada 
          }else{ 
Intent intent = new Intent(CatTegnologiaActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

podrias probar con lo siguiente.

```
//Ubicacion_ y Area_ supongo que son el segundo o el tercer campo
if (Ubicacion_.length()==0 && Area_.length()== 0){
    //no hace nada 
}else{ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(CatTegnologiaActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
}
```

O de una manera mas corta seria.

```
//Ubicacion_ y Area_ supongo que son el segundo o el tercer campo
//El ! es para negar la afirmacion
if (!(Ubicacion_.length()==0 && Area_.length()== 0)){
    Intent intent = new Intent(CatTegnologiaActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
}
```